# Why do we need 50 reputation to make comments?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

You need to have 50 reputation to make a comment on an answer but you can post an answer to a question with far fewer reputation. I was curious what the mindset was behind this decision? I know I'd like to add a comment at times but do not have enough reputation to do so. My comment really isn't an answer, so posting there would be wrong which leaves me not really being able to be of any help or add any insight to the OP.

Comment: Spam is, I believe, the only underlying reason.

Comment: There is an answer on Meta Stack Exchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120454/revisit-new-users-cant-ask-for-clarifications-except-as-answers

Comment: You can also suggest edits with a reputation of 1!

Comment: [Reputation Cheat sheet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

Comment: @J.Steen - Here is a comment from the link rene mentioned, "I've often thought this restriction just turns good comments into bad answers, and spam comments into spam answers. What spammer would be discouraged by needing to make their spam more prominent?".

Comment: @iCobot: Answers both a) bump the post to the front page, where others see it and flag it b) go through a First Posts review automatically. (Having said that, I've long though the requirements for comments should be more like 25)

Comment: I never said it was a reason that covered *all* avenues of spamming. I'm just saying that's the reason. =)

Comment: If you couldn't comment or answer, how would you get reputation?

Comment: @podiluska through the painful process of asking a good question and waiting for something like badges to happen. Only one question, but if its good enough, it just might work(?) perhaps.

Comment: I see these sometimes in the lqp queue and to be frank they are the most annoying type of user.  Maybe the software can intervene if the answer contains a single paragraph ending with "?" and say "Are you sure this is an answer?"  My view is that using an answer to make a comment is petulance!  Not very tolerant on that one, sorry.

Comment: @iCobot: I would give you at leats 100 upvotes for this question. I had this problem many times. The ONLY thing I could do, is not be active on those SE websites anymore. It's just sad how on such a big community driven websites you cannot help someone.

Comment: Whoever thought it was a good idea to not allow anyone with less than 50 rep to comment clearly didn't think this through... If I got a penny for every time I've seen a new user post an answer like `This should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation points to comment yet`, I'd be rich. Not only does the inability for new users to comment encourage them to post comments as answers (due to the lack of alternatives), the subsequent, aggressive downvoting and/or deleting of such poor answers will only discourage well-meaning new users from participating in this community altogether.

Comment: I agree with @JohnSlegers. Comments are the most natural way to gain entry into our community, and the reputation barrier forces them to write poorly thought out answers before understanding the expectations.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

A new user who posts an answer will most likely know (if they know anything at all) that their answer is going to be voted on and will affect their reputation on the site. New answers are also generally more visible than comments are. They are shown in some of the review queues. A new answer will make the question appear earlier in the active questions list. And so on and so forth. So they are going to get some eyeballs. There's a good incentive there to post good answers. And even if the people posting don't *know* all this, there's still a whole system in place for evaluating answers.

Comments do not contribute in the reputation system. There are no downvotes for comments. Comments are not as visible as answers are. So there's not as much of an incentive to post good contents in comments. Then other people have to flag bad comments for removal, and moderators have to act to remove them, etc.

The reputation requirement is an *imperfect* means to help prevent bad contents. It surely does not prevent all problems and there are surely people with a reputation of 1 who *could* post great comments.

Comment: That is understandable.  I have said this before and I am not one to be on here to just gain reputation nor am I on here enough to be looking for questions I know I can easily answer to get my reputation up more quickly.  Most of the time I find a post it has already been answered so posting another one just to gain reputation is kind of pointless to me.  I was above the 50 point mark at one point and 2 questions were down voted to an oblivion which killed my reputation points.

Comment: Also, I would up vote your answer but I do not have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @dlf Yeah, I went and checked your answers. They are actually answers, so no problem there. :)

Comment: @Louis: I deleted my comment at the exact moment you posted yours, so I guess that means I have to put it back. :) I'm new here myself. There were several occasions where I wanted to post a comment asking for more information, but since I couldn't I just took my best guess and answered instead. And got rep for it since I happened to guess right. :)

Comment: I still think it's strange to not allow an asker to upvote or downvote answers to their own questions while allowing them to comment on them and mark them accepted cc @iCobot

Comment: @BoltClock - Another beauty is lets say I make a mistake and up vote a post.  If I try to down vote that same post, I can't do it if I do not have 125 reputation points.

Comment: @iCobot: Well, un-upvoting is different from downvoting...

Comment: I don't think this is the reason why at all, these are just your personal opinions - you are essentially making up a rationale. The reason why was some spam prevention debate. This has been discussed on meta many times before.

Comment: @Lundin The OP asks: "you need to have 50 reputation points to make a comment on an answer but you can post an answer to a question with far fewer reputation points. I was curious what the mindset was behind the decision between the two?" Saying that you need 50 rep to post comments because of spam does not explain *why you don't need the same rep to post questions and answers, which are also subject to spam*. Furthermore, the fact that comments are not given as much visibility also affects how likely trash *other than spam* will survive in a comment vs trash in an actual post.

Comment: @Louis I'm actually pretty sure that I have asked the very same question myself at some point - because the 50 rep limit doesn't make any sense, given that answers have higher expectations. A mod or dev replied that it was because they didn't have the same kind of spam prevention mechanisms and moderator tools for comments as they have for answers. In addition, users can moderate answers but not comments. So this has nothing to do with vague things like visibility or impact of answers compared to comments, but rather with site moderation limitations. The answer from Brad Larson confirms this.

Comment: Love the last line of this answer, it is imperfect, but it is there for a good attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: If we limited the amount of daily comments to 5 or 10 before the 50 threshold people would think smartly when they add any comment. Especially, if it's not only the be awesome! +1! It won't be perfect, but it would be a better solution that restricting them to no comment and allowing bad answers.

Answer (score 36):

Comments were added to the site after questions and answers existed, and remain second-class citizens here. We have robust moderation tools and review systems for handling questions and answers, but lack similar tools for comments.

Stack Overflow (like all user-contributed-content sites anywhere near its size) is constantly under attack from spammers and trolls, but most people don't see any of that due to how effective community moderation and anti-spam countermeasures are at blocking and removing this. Spam and trolling would overrun comments here if we didn't have some minimum barrier for posting them.

We also want to prevent YouTube-style noise in comments, pruning comments to only those that add to the information contained in the posts they are left on.

However, I believe that with proper tooling, Stack Overflow might be able to open up comments to new users in the way that we do questions and answers. I expand on this a bit in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226183/135615), but something like the current review queues for posts by new users could be applied to incoming comments. It would be a great help to have the ability to search comments and more easily remove problematic ones. Other things would need to be put in place as well, but these are a few suggestions to start with.

I think we eventually need tools like this in any case, since we've now seen several incidents where spammers used sock puppet accounts or plagiarized answers to gain enough reputation where they could leave comments and then proceeded to spam comments on hundreds of highly-voted questions or answers. This spam hung around for months, because it was hard to see, difficult to find, and a pain to remove. We also need better ways of dealing with patterns of rude and abusive comments left by certain users.

The inability of new users to post clarifying comments or requests for additional information in order to answer a question leads to a lot of frustration by new users and is one of the primary causes of non-answers being left to questions. I believe proper moderation and review tools to handle comments could make for a more pleasant new-user experience and possibly cut down on moderation workload by reducing the number of non-answers we have to delete.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow shares a history of success with Wikipedia. It also shares the challenge of balancing the desire to attract new contributors with the need to manage the varying quality of contributions from new and anonymous users.

Wikipedia also has a gradation of user privileges. The contributions of new and anonymous users are queued for review. Once you are a member of the club, you earn the right to create articles that are immediately visible. Even so, there are races to claim article titles and other such monkey business. One difference is that every keystroke in Wikipedia is traceable to a user. There is no anonymous voting.

I am writing this answer because I am a newbie. I have no authority to post a comment. As a result of being an answer, it is out for votes. I raised a similar (but not identical) topic. It was quickly downvoted 17 times. The comments were not kind, but I had no opportunity to respond.

Specific to questions in the main site, a review of the recently posted questions will uncover many rapid responses with short, if correct, answers.  Because they are not formal answers, the author does not risk rejection of the response. When the proper response is that the question is vague, duplicative, or lacks sufficient data, the new user has no choice but to write that in the formal answer box. What will be the result? Brickbats.

Responses on Wikipedia are no less edgy, but the new contributor is not restricted from responding or looking at the website traffic statistics. Sure, there may be a review gate, but it's not locked. New users even have a special moderated chat board. Instead of looking at a locked gate, the new contributor gets a guided tour from an experienced contributor. It's worth a thought.

I am surprised that a commenter to this discussion writes "You can earn 50 reputation in 2 minutes if you answer a question well enough." And I can make the U.S. Olympic team if I run 2:10 at the trials.

Stack Overflow would do well to watch what happens on Wikipedia. The subhead in Pacific Standard magazine read, "A hardened corps of volunteer editors is the only force protecting Wikipedia. They might also be killing it." I point out the words *hardened volunteers*. Here are a couple of sentences that capture the essence.

> Forced to defend the site’s integrity, incumbent editors become
> skeptical, even hostile, toward the newcomers who could ensure its
> future. If Wikipedia eventually fades away, the reasons will lie in a
> culture that worked brilliantly until it devolved from dynamism to
> sclerosis.

Sure, I'm a newbie at Stack Overflow, but I believe that I understand how a cooperative knowledge base can work. I created 94 articles on the English language Wikipedia and made 6000 edits in the last year. Really, truly, it's not that much different. Both are evidence-based repositories of human knowledge.

Please think first before you downvote or use your comment authority to reprimand a newbie. That person may have something to offer in the long term, but not be ready for the rough-and-tumble.

Comment: "The comments were not kind, but I had no opportunity to respond." You can always post comments on your own posts, or on answers to your own questions, unless they are locked (in which case *no one* can post comments).

Comment: If you're good at editing, edit 25 posts to get 50 reputation.

Answer (score -3):

ADDITION:

One aspect of reaching the 50 point threshold is the ability to post comments freely on the OP and answers to the OP. But that means there is no further risk in providing answers. I notice people doing a lot of conversational posts, suggestions, and requests for info using comments to the point of answering or solving the OP, while no formal answer is ever given. People such as me, who are new, have no choice but to use formal answers, try to build up points, and take hits when answers are not well received. People have downvoted a couple of my answers, not saying why, just because it isn't liked for some reason. Because of that I have difficulty reaching 50 points where formal answers aren't even needed anymore. Doing a proper answer requires research. A suggestion does not and can be put in a comment. I fail to see how this is fair and tends to retard participation. I hope to reach 50 points, but I must say it takes a lot of extra effort, along with a tad bit of frustration that I can read what other people post without being able to do so myself.

ORIGINAL:

I was recently chastised on one of my answers by being told it was more of a comment than an answer. But I don't have enough points to make comments. So I can't do anything it would seem. I was going to post in the meta forum about this, but instead found this thread, and am putting my comment here. Maybe this will go to the top, too.

If a person has sufficient points to post comments in one forum, there may not be enough in another forum. What if a person has been using Stack Exchange a long time before joining the new site?

Why not represent points across all Stack Exchange sites? If a person is good in one site, that person should also be good in others. At least comments should be allowed based on points across all sites, but maybe other functions should be allowed, too.

Comment: So, you really want someone established on [cooking.SE] to have that same towering reputation on [SO]? Not a good idea. Anyway, if you gain 200 rep on any SE-site, you will get a 100 point association-bonus on all sites for all connected accounts, whenever you get around to connecting / opening those accounts (including all previous ones). That gets you beyond all new-user-restrictions, due to basic familiarity with the system.

Comment: Did not know about connector points, thanks. But to a great extent, what applies in one forum applies to all forums, at least what I've seen in the stackexchange forums. If a person has experience in any forum here, that person [most likely] will have enough sense not to answer a question without reasoning or evidence, So yes, I would favor a person from any SE site being able to post in stackoverflow if he or she wanted to.

Comment: Anybody can post. And as @Deduplicator already mentioned, the association bonus gives you enough rep to comment on any site once you get 200 on one. I occasionally visit other SE sites, and found that the culture can be quite different from SO. It makes sense to me to get the basic privileges, but still have to earn anything more. BTW, you're not allowed to call this site a "forum".

Comment: @Reto: Stack Exchange sites are fora... but they are Q&A fora, not discussion fora.  Go ahead and stomp on people calling using the term "discussion forum", or bare "forum" in a way that implies discussion forum.  But when you see "in this forum" or "in any forum", that's correct usage of the English word forum, meaning a public place.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't really care myself, the remark was slightly sarcastic. I've seen people get all bent out of shape when somebody just used the word. I used it by accident once around here, and people jumped on me like I had said something very dirty. I sort of understand where they're coming from, but it's really a very generic word.

Comment: If this is not another forum we must necessarily have another definition, and bureaucracy to make that happy. If not "forum" then what?

Answer (score -8):

The irony of the Stack Overflow reputation system is that it creates more question and answer traffic, but at the expense of answer quality.

In order to answer questions to improve your reputation, you need to spend time monitoring unanswered questions and then try to answer them. This self-selects for people who are into the hobbyist gamified aspect of the site, or those with the free (or work) time to trawl through Stack Overflow answering random questions, or more often those who are happy to flip off a 1 line answer that helps but does not answer the question. The most authoritative answers come from those who reply when they are already on the site looking for something else, however these people are often excluded from contributing due to low reputation from not answering tons of random questions.

In my case, I’ve been using Stack Overflow since it began; I use it at least once per week, but my reputation is 11. Over the years, I’ve had hundreds of opportunities to correct or improve a wrong accepted answer, update an outdated answer which no longer works or is allowed in a particular platform, or to address incorrect or outdated comments. I’ve been in the tech industry for 40+ years across countless platforms, and yet unless I spend a heap of time managing each individual step in the Stack Overflow reputation process, my knowledge isn’t welcome.

Sure, that’s just the nature of how this imperfect process works, but keep in mind that they intentionally designed the process this way. Stack Overflow by now has the resources to improve the reputation system if they wanted to, but this isn’t the end goal. Eyeballs and user traffic is the end goal, not knowledge or answer quality. A quick look at the questions with lots of different answers clearly shows this.

In answer to your question, the mindset is that they designed the reputation system this way because it gamifies it in a way that brings in the most traffic. You, as an expert in your domain, aren't a "primary" design goal.

Comment: If an answer is wrong, or does not get things sufficiently right, and you have the expertise to point that out and explain things properly, then you can do readers *and* yourself a favor by pointing it out. That way, others will get a more informative answer *and* you'll probably get an upvote or few. If you try answering a few questions, you can get to 50 rep in no time at all.

Comment: You can post authoritative, high-quality answers without needing any rep whatsoever, so I really don't understand how your complaint is germane.

Comment: No, it was designed for quick answers. And it worked (too well - so [the Eternal September event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) happened before anyone was prepared to deal with it (even though both founders had lived through the pain and misery of the original one. And the following horrible, horrible forums)).

Comment: 7 upvotes on comments, all supporting comments saying that I can answer questions without reputation, implying my point is invalid, when I didn't say any such thing. Read my answer more carefully before commenting or upvoting so quickly and offhandedly, which arguably validates my point regarding the quality of many SO answers. I really do appreciate the advice on how to fix my reputation, but I also do understand the reputation system. I’m not complaining about it or demanding change, I’m just pointing out how inadequate the system is, in answer to a question on why 50 reputation points.

Comment: If you had used the "opportunities to correct or improve a wrong accepted answer", chances are that some of those edits would have accepted and you'd have enough reputation to comment, no? Regardless of the gratification of reputation points, comments are less monitored than Answers, and even accounts created ages ago are used for spam. One can just create one and let it sit for a few years before using it for nefarious purposes.

Answer (score -14):

There's a workaround for that (that I use myself):

You could post an answer with *your solution that could be devised from the information provided* and *requesting more info in order to provide a complete solution* (probably pointing out the asker should do it as an update to the question rather than a comment if the author is a novice themselves). Then just update the answer appropriately as they add the information requested.

Of course, this would only work **if you're genuinely trying to resolve OP's problem** and *not just dump your idle thoughts (tangentially) on the subject* - that's another major reason for the threshold to exist.

Sure, this is only possible when a question gives anywhere enough information to give just *any* answer that would not be flagged and deleted as a comment. I assure you, this isn't much of a problem: the vast majority of questions that don't do that get closed or deleted anyway.

Examples of my answers that were composed in this way:

- [Python application using Twisted stops running after user logs off of Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674277/python-application-using-twisted-stops-running-after-user-logs-off-of-windows-xp/9675842#9675842)
- [Pythonic way to find the file with a given name closest to a specific directory location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148459/pythonic-way-to-find-the-file-with-a-given-name-closest-to-a-specific-directory/17149192#17149192)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812613/site-visible-on-new-ip-client-sees-old-ip-ping-request-timed-out-on-new-ip/14812791#14812791 - the OP never provided the info requested but the answer never got downvoted [as iCobot fears](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/50-reputation-points-to-make-comments/276915?noredirect=1#comment117916_276915) either
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873185/flask-windows-service-doesnt-spawn-child-process/24888762#24888762 - same as the previous one
- [Hierarchical SQL select-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463818/hierarchical-sql-select-query/26468774#26468774)

Comment: I believe people refrain from doing this suggestion because initially they would be down voted as it would be going against the grain so to say.  In the end, it could have its totals reversed but then again maybe not if people are not revisiting the answer they down voted already.   See user1671787 as an example below.

Comment: @iCobot okay, I didn't think this was needed, but - a few counterexamples are in order!

Comment: @ivan_pozdeez - You do not need counter examples.  This isn't a whose right and who isn't.  The rules state comments shouldn't be answers and trying to disguise your comment as an answer is against the rules.  Comments, from what I have seen, are used to ask for more information not the answers.

Comment: @iCobot Did you read my answer carefully? The whole point is to provide an answer that *is not a comment* and *request clarification at the same time*.

Comment: Yes I read your answer as you updated it like 4+ times since the initial posting.  It starts out as a comment and you eventually formulate it into an answer.  Regardless how you spin it, you are still bending the rules to try and make your case more valid.  Some of the examples you gave do not have any editing from the OP.  So it's not like the OP was providing more detail to his original posting.

Comment: Where am I bending the rules? Think out of the box. The meaning of posting an answer is to provide a complete answer to the quesiton. If there's not enough info, a complete answer *at this point* is what can be devised from existing info and requesting more if the author wishes me to be able to help him any further.

Comment: I am all for thinking out of the box and what programmers need to do at times.  It's kind of a necessary trait to a degree.  If you are posting an initial comment and then turning it into an answer eventually, that's bending the rules as you are posting an initial comment and then turning it into an answer.  I am not here to argue with you about it.  If you have a partial answer and then update it to a complete answer, that is different.  Also asking me if I read your answer thoroughly after you updated it a bunch of times is pretty shady.  Take care.

Comment: This is not a good idea; only answer if you can actually answer the question. As @iCobot has insinuated, answering questions in a roundabout way to ask for more information will get your posts into review queues that you do not want them to be in.