# How are users who do not have 50 rep, supposed to answer a question which requires additional information?

Tags: discussion

They can't comment to ask additional info. And they're not allowed to "answer" the question to ask for additional information.

Comment: They move on to a question that *is* clear, or wait for others to ask.

Comment: Related: [50 reputation points to make comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252133)

Answer (score 6):

If this is the case, then just leave that question (perhaps favourite/bookmark it for later) and search for a question you *can* answer without asking for more information.

Then when you've done this a couple of time and got the requisite 50 reputation points, *then* you can go back and revisit the earlier question(s) and ask for more information to your heart's content.

Ultimately, if you don't have 50 rep, you're not supposed to answer these questions. There are plenty of other questions - it's not questions that Stack Overflow is short of.

Comment: It's questions I might be able to answer, which are scarce.