# Why do I need 50 reputation to improve other people's answers when appropriate?

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation

This is just ridiculous. I have been using Stack Overflow for quite some time and when I find an answer which I can extend or improve, I can't because I don't have enough points, and this system is ridiculous. I don't need to ask questions because most questions have already been answered!

Comment: you do realize that this kind of complaint isn't going to resonate well, right?

Comment: just answer questions and gain rep.

Comment: This "question" shows that you *shouldn't* be able to freely edit.

Comment: After migration I was able to upvote @NinaScholz comment again :P

Comment: I downvoted the question too, but the comment upvotes weren't restarted

Comment: _"I don't need to ask questions because most questions have already been answered!"_ Isn't that exactly the goal we wanted to reach?

Comment: @PeterMortensen He's not asking to be able to comment; he's asking to be able to edit.

Comment: The canonical question seems to be *[50 reputation points to make comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133)* (depending on what extend or improve means exactly - it could be referring to posting comments in order to suggest improvement to the poster or others).

Answer (score 34):

You **don't** need 50 reputation to improve other people's questions and answers. In fact, *you don't need to be logged in at all* (the 'edit' link is then called 'improve this question/answer'). Your *suggested* edits don't apply immediately; they will be put into a [queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) where they will be reviewed by other users.