# Newbie: comment or new question?

Tags: support

I am a newbie in programming as well as on Stack Overflow.

As a newbie, I have probably a very “naïve” question: What should I do, when I find a thread where my problem is already described, but the answer does not work in my case?

I cannot add an answer because I have a question. I cannot add a comment because of my low reputation. And initiating a new thread is not the best way (in my opinion): duplicate threads blow up the forum and make the search through it more tedious. Can I go a different way?

Comment: Related: [50 reputation points to make comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/50-reputation-points-to-make-comments)

Comment: @RobertLongson: I suggest you post your comment as an answer as it is the correct way to do it :)

Comment: @Robert: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I see your point, but does this behaviour not increment the number of posts unnecessarily?  Or there is an advantage in acting this way that I do not recognise?

Comment: Exactly what @RobertLongson. If the answer of the original question does not meet your needs then explain that in your question. In the long run your question may help others who have faced the same issue.

Comment: @hering: I would follow your suggestion... I only have one doubt: Do other Stack Overflow users understand and accept this solution?

Comment: @dade100 are they upvoting my answer?

Comment: @dade100 'they' would be anyone who votes. You were not impolite, You'll find out if other stack overflow users understand and accept an answer by their votes. If they upvote they understand and accept something, if they downvote the opposite is likely true.

Comment: @Robert: Yes, they are upvoting your answer. Cannot you see that? Personally, I would like to upvote by I cannot because of my low reputation...

Comment: I can, my statement was to inform you that that's how things work around here.

Comment: Also note that Stack Exchange is *not* a forum; we do not have 'threads' in the sense of a forum.

Answer (score 98):

Ask a new question, referring to the original question as necessary. Explain what you did and what your results are and how they differ from the expected results.

Comment: Overall, showing your research efforts as part of the question is encouraged. Links to which SO posts or other documentation you have read and why they didn't answer your particular question.

Comment: It must still be noted: before asking, make sure your question isn't a duplicate, unclear or any of the other close reasons.

Comment: To avoid your question being closed as duplicate, list related questions and clearly state why your problem is different from their questions and not solvable by their answers.

Answer (score 16):

To add to what Robert said, here's what I look for in a non-duplicate

1. Reference the duplicate. Link to it in the question. At the bare minimum, you've now demonstrated that you've done your homework and at least made an effort (most dupes fail this miserably, i.e. "I got this error! *dumps code* Help!")
2. Explain what didn't work. Giving your examples are critical here
3. **Contrast with the other question**. This is the real gotcha of duplicates. It's possible to do #1 and #2 and still be a duplicate. There needs to be something different. Too often people think that, just because this doesn't cover my specific case, it's not a dupe, while ignoring the principles of the dupe itself. This is where you stand out in my book (and where a lot of dupes get reopened). Make the case that this is different in your question

   > The other question was about feeding turtles but I'm trying to feed *constipated* turtles

This isn't a guarantee that you still won't get closed as a dupe (hopefully a closer will explain why it is if it comes to that), but it greatly reduces those chances.

Answer (score 2):

It's great that you're concerned about adding to the noise and making it more difficult for people to find answers to their questions, but I think you're worrying unnecessarily in this case.

Other answers have already covered what to do: ask a new question, show your research, link back to existing related question(s), and explain why your scenario is different. But I'm not sure the other answers have quite explained to you why this isn't just adding to the noise - and that in fact, you'd be making it *easier* for people to find answers.

Very often when I'm looking for an answer to a programming problem, I search on Google and end up with some results from Stack Overflow. I click on the one that sounds the most similar from the title and preview. However, fairly frequently, that isn't where I find my answer. I read through, realise the question and answers don't quite solve my problem, and navigate to questions shown on the side bar as "Linked" (or less frequently, those shown under "Related"). Or sometimes I click on links to other questions directly within the original question, one of the answers, or even a comment.

Even though the question I initially landed on in this scenario wasn't quite right, it lead me to the right place. By having a number of similar-but-different questions here on Stack Overflow, there are more chances that my specific Google search receives at least one of the linked questions in my results. The linked questions act as sign posts to one another.

Further to this, sometimes reading one question and set of answers doesn't quite give me a full picture. Sometimes I find I read through several similar questions which all answer part of what I'm trying to find out, and perhaps after reading 3 or 4 I have the answer, without ever needing to ask a question of my own.

So even if your question is 95% the same as another one, you're adding not only that last 5% to the body of knowledge, but you're probably helping people find the older question more frequently.