# Pay to comment to open commenting for low rep users

Tags: feature-request, comments

Stack Overflow requires users to have 50+ reputation to post a comment. While it should not be too hard to get [50 reputation points to make comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/50-reputation-points-to-make-comments), many people ask for personal exceptions to let them comment.

I propose to let users buy permission to comment if they feel a particular comment is very important. The comments should be relatively expensive (5$-10$?) and should not be marked/treated in any special way (with reputation of the user to be the only indication of possibly paid comment).

Benefits:

- people who have a very strong desire to provide "that one comment" can do so
- requests for individual exceptions to allow commenting will have two alternatives (time - 50 rep, or money)

Other considerations:

- with relatively high price per comment, spamming in comments would be very unlikely. Some restrictions on methods of payment and frequency of payment from the same card (or other payment identity) may be considered. Accounts with "spam" or "abusive" flags may need to be excluded completely.
- SO/SE already have support for collecting money (SO for teams) - limiting payments to just the same as accepted there may prevent a flood of fraudulent purchases...
- it needs to be made clear to users that such comments would not have any additional protections/promotion (i.e. can be deleted as any other comments when flagged). Making users read information that is already forced on them is hard, but I hope users will read large font before clicking "buy one comment" button.
- if implemented this may prompt other "pay to skip rate limits/bans" features which in my mind is not too bad to have - paying to *provide* content is not against the SO model to my understanding...

What price point to use per comment - I think between "slightly above the average phone app cost" and "less than the average hourly salary of a beginner developer" is a good place. 5-10$ range to me looks like a good starting point as it is a noticeable sum but not out of reach of most people. Hopefully it will make one think about better alternatives (maybe full answer is more appropriate or just getting those 50 rep).

Comment: Honestly I would propose increasing the threshold. 50 is too low to really avoid spams and non needed comments.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This would be appalling.

People paying for something have different expectations to those getting something for free (at least after they've participated in the site enough to get 50 reputation).

I can see people complaining "but I paid for that!" in cases where their comment was removed for any reason.

I can see people wanting to claim that "they can say anything I like" because there was a monetary transaction involved.

And that doesn't even touch on the development work that would be required to support this.

No, this is a bad idea.

Comment: I can see people paying to add comment and suddenly the post is deleted (contact customer sevice, refunds, etc, etc).

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I hadn't even thought of that aspect!

Comment: Summary - users will never ever read description of what they are buying...

Comment: *I can see people complaining "but I paid for that!" * but we have them pay for complaining as well. I call that win-win. It is an awesome idea. ...